# How should I write view unittest in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I want to write a unittest for this method in Django.

```
def activate(request):
    id = int(request.GET.get('id'))
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
    return render(request, 'user_authentication/activation.html')
```

I wrote sth like this:

```
def test_activate_view(self):
    response = self.client.get('/activation', follow=True)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'user_authentication/activation.html')
```

It doesn't work because I get an error:

```
id = int(request.GET.get('id'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType':
```

What should I change in my test ?

Comment: Well, the test has found a bug: you'll get a 500 error if someone doesn't pass an `id=..` parameter in the GET request. You should probably fix the bug first ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your view reads data from `request.GET` - you need to pass this data:

```
response = self.client.get('/activation?id=1', follow=True)
```

You also fetch this user afterwards from your database. Therefor you need to load some fixture data. Create a fixture using `manage.py dumpdata` and load it in your unit test like that:

```
class UserTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['fixture.json', 'users']
```

[Read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading) about loading fixtures for detailed explanations.

**Note regarding your approach**

You should not use the users `id` for this use case. One can easily guess this `id` and activate accounts.

Someone might register once with a valid email address, receive your link with the `id` inside and can afterwards create a bunch of accounts without providing a valid email address.

Instead you might generate a unique and random secret (aka **token**) and associate this token with the user. Your view should accept those tokens and resolve the user based on it. This way one can no longer easily activate.

Comment: Django's built-in password reset by email, has all the functionality needed to do this right: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html